# How to create an array of strings from a given line in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
char a[100]="You are welcome";
```

Now how can I make the words in this line into array of strings?

```
char b[5][20];
strcpy(b[0],"you");
strcpy(b[1],"are");
strcpy(b[2],"welcome");
```

In this way, we can make array of strings.

But I want to do dynamically for any giving input ?

Please help...

Comment: in TCL, we can do by splitting the line [split $line " "] and then all words ll be in list elements. Is there any similar procedure in C?

Answer (score 3):

`strtok` is your friend:

```
char a[] = "You are welcome";
char b[5][20] = {{0}};
char *pch;

pch = strtok( a," \t" );
int i = 0;
while( NULL != pch && i < 5)
{
    strcpy(b[i++], pch);
    pch = strtok( NULL, " \t\n" );
}

for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
{
    if( strlen(b[i]) > 0 )
    {
        printf( "b[%d] = %s\n", i, b[i] );
    }
}
```

Don't forget to `#include <string.h>`

---

As David C. Rankin pointed out. We can do away with `strlen` by just checking the first char not `\0`. So this'd be a better solution (note that the main `while` loop for `strtok` processing remains the same).

```
i = 0; 
while (*b[i]) 
{ 
    printf( "b[%d] = %s\n", i, b[i] ); 
    i++; 
}
```

Comment: Since you properly initialize your `b` array, to iterate over all strings copied to the array (presuming you always leave `b[4]...` empty) , you can iterate over the strings with `while (*b[i]) printf( "b[%d] = %s\n", i, b[i] );` (you can do the same with a dynamically allocated array of pointers-to-char by insuring you `realloc` before assigning a value to the last pointer).

Comment: No, you already initialized all characters to `0` with `char b[5][20] = {{0}};`, so simply checking whether the first char is something other than `0` allows you to avoid the additional call to `strlen` `:)` -- try it, replace your entire print loop with the `while (*b[i])` loop. (you do need to insure you set `i = 0;` before the loop and `i++` at the end)

Comment: Give it a try `i = 0; while (*b[i]) { printf( "b[%d] = %s\n", i, b[i] ); i++; }`

Answer (score 0):

[Reference:strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)

You can go for a "scanf" in place of "printf" inside while loop, and store the values in second array(b in your case)

```
 while (pch != NULL)   {
     printf ("%s\n",pch);
     pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");   }
```